# firebase onSnapshot not updating data in real time

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm learning firebase and I'm baffled because I'm following the tutorial to the dot, literally copy and paste and though the following code:

```
// init firebase
initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

// init services
const db = getFirestore()

// collection ref
const colRef = collection(db, 'books')

// real time collection data
onSnapshot(colRef, (snapshot) => {
  let books = []
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    books.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
  })
  console.log(books)
})

// adding docs
const addBookForm = document.querySelector('.add')
addBookForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  addDoc(colRef, {
    title: addBookForm.title.value,
    author: addBookForm.author.value,
  })
  .then(() => {
    addBookForm.reset()
   })
 })
```

in the tutorial results in data being updated live (changes are reflected in the console, as users add/removes books), on my app changes are reflected only after refreshing the page.
I did some digging but only managed to find people with similar issue but no answer, i tried changing `snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => ...)` to `snapshot.docChanges().forEach(doc => ...)`. same result.

Comment: What javascript are you using? Is it ReactJS or the native one? If you're using the native javascript then i would suggest using `AJAX` to handle realtime changes. If you're using ReactJS, use `useEffect()` instead.

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB so I'm integrating my own project with firebase simultaneously with the tutorial and my project is in React, where i used `useEffect` as you said (though i didn't put `onSnapshot` inside there, only `addDoc()`) and it's working fine. The project from the tutorial is in plain JS and I'm doing everything like in the video, just so i can follow along and for some reason I got different results.

Comment: If you're integrating it on React then that would be the expected behavior as it needs React hook to interact with the `onSnapshot`. You cannot follow the tutorial in plain JS as it differs from ReactJS. I would suggest following this [guide](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-react-hooks-firebase-firestore/) instead.

Comment: no, what i did in React works (btw, i used `onSnapshot`), it didn't work with plain JS, like i said i ended up literally copy & paste the tutorial code.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible code that includes the working UI that you said is not working. Please also include your `package.json` if possible for us to be able to use the specific version of your installed packages.

Comment: the code in my question is the working code that is not working for me. my package.json is `{
  "name": "tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode=development"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.12.1"
  }
}
` copy&paste author's package.json also doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working for you but I created a working sample of your code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7c8Lfu63/5/). Just put your firebase configuration on the `firebaseConfig` variable. Let me know if you have clarifications.

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB thanks for that, tried your code, same results. It works only after refreshing the page, just like the tutorial code. It meant to log new collection to the console, immediately after adding the book, without refreshing the page, that's what supposedly `onSnapshot` was meant to be for. That's what it does on the tutorial. It's clear to me now , that code is not the issue, maybe something with the browser, don't know. Like i said, i'm not the first one to have this exact issue, but people who asked before didn't get a solution either, so  i was expecting it to be a long shot.

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB anyway, i have now successfully connected my react app (appointment planner) with firestore, it works great, so that was my goal, but clearly that's something to mindful for future.